# Faking normal font

Tags: fonts, fontspec

Some fonts, though regular/normal, appear quite bold face (or thick) in output. Is there a way to reduce the thickness of a font? Sort of a reverse fake-bold or a direct fake-thin?

Comment: Generally not. Which compiler do you use? Especially, which fonts did you have in mind? There is a reason why some fonts (intended for book print) are slightly heavier than others.

Comment: It might be possible, but there aren't enough details to answer the question. A concrete example would help.

Comment: I am using xelatex with polyglossia, and the font in question is an old legacy font called Vilna.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to fake Bookman, for example. But the result looks like completely different font:

```
\input cbookman

\def\fakethin#1{\pdfliteral{2 Tr 1 G .2 w}#1\pdfliteral{0 Tr 0 w 0 G}}

Hello \fakethin{Hello}

\bye
```

(use pdftex)

[image: faked Bookman]

Comment: Actually, that looks like a variation on the same font. Fonts are classified by a number of criteria, of interest to typographers. The main problem is that there needs to be less thinning applied to strokes that are already thin (particularly horizontals). The FontForge program can edit fonts by changing weight, and can distinguish between thick/thin and horizontal/vertical strokes. More problematic with diagonals.